# Can you use Dart to write cloud functions for a flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

Can you use Dart to write Firebase cloud functions for a flutter app?  Has anyone done this?  If so, is it viable long-term or is it better to use JavaScript /TypeScript?

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dart/tree/main?

Comment: Yes I had seen that thanks.  I was hoping to use Firebase Cloud Functions.  I've found an article here https://medium.com/icnh/writing-cloud-functions-in-dart-b7e62192b3bc - I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

As of the time of writing this answer, these are the supported languages: NodeJs, Python, Ruby, Go, Java, PHP and .NET.

Dart is not listed as one of the supported languages for Google Cloud Functions: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#runtimes

Maybe they'll add Dart in the future, but I haven't heard of it.

Comment: I'm asking about firebase cloud functions, which are not quite the same thing as google cloud functions.
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd].  Officially supported languages are typescript, javascript and python but I think some people use Dart.

Comment: @Alpha They are the same thing. Firebase Functions are just GCP Cloud Functions with wrappers for easier integration with the Firebase sub ecosystem.

Comment: Yes I know it's GCP behind the scenes but that's not relevant to my question.

Comment: It is relevant to your question; you asked if you can write **Firebase** Cloud Functions in Dart, and the answer is no. You could spin up a container that runs your Dart program, but that is not a **Firebase** Cloud Function.